# What's the best way to initialize object derived from monobehavior?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

We can't use constructor in class derived from Monobehavior, so we define "Initialze" method to simulate constructor, defination like this:

```
public class Animal : Monobehavior
{
    public void Initialize(string animalName)
    {
        // initialze animal
    }
}
```

Then, there is is dog class, which has different initialize parameter list:

```
public class Dog : Animal 
{
    // Cannot override because different parameter list
    public void Initialize(string animalName, Bone favoriteBone)
    {
        base.Initialize(animalName);
        // initialze dog
    }
}
```

Then, we create animal object like this:

```
var animalInstance = Instantiate(animalPrefab);
animalInstance.Initialize("animal name");
```

And we create dog object like this:

```
var dogInstance = Instantiate(dogPrefab);
dogInstance.Initialize("dog name", new Bone());
```

There is the problem, we can still call the "dogInstance.Initialize("dog name")" without Bone parameter, unlike C# constructor, if someday I'm drunk and write down the stupid code (or someone else come to write it), it's a big trouble.

So, is there a best way to initialize object derived from monobehavior?

Comment: FYI: People can write broken code in every programming language, at some point it has to become the programmers responsibility to not do so

Comment: However you might want to look into the "factory pattern" to abstract this creation + initialization away, so you don't type it out every time by hand

Comment: You can do initialization at `void Start()` method. It is called when the object gets created.

Comment: Why is your Animal class non abstract?
You should mark it as abstract and hide the common code in protected virtual methods. Then every (useful) derived class can provide it's own public Initialize method with different signature.
Still you should add a factory pattern as @UnholySheep suggested.

Comment: @N.Dogac OP's question is about initializing the instance with certain values .. something you can't do with `Start`

Answer (score 2):

You can branch out the instantiation of basic animals. You can make the `Animal` class to be an `abstract` base class (with its `Initialize(string)` being `protected`).

From `Animal` you can derive `SimpleAnimal` that will be used instead when you want to instantiate some basic animal. Then you will have Animal to derive from and SimpleAnimal to instantiate.

E.g. like

```
public abstract class Animal : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    protected void Initialize(string animalName)
    {
        Name = animalName;
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public void Initialize(string animalName, Bone favoriteBone)
    {
        base.Initialize(animalName);

        // initialze dog
    }
}

public class SimpleAnimal : Animal
{
    public new void Initialize(string animalName)
    {
        base.Initialize(animalName);
    }
}
```

Comment: I felt so free to add some code implementation from your description .. I hope that is ok ;)

Comment: Of course, thanks! Was on the phone and it's  difficult for me to post from there anything but simple text.